# Не записываются данные в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Доброй ночи, господа. Приведенный ниже код должен записывать `id` новости в колонку `posts_id` в базу данных при `INSERT`, тоже самое и при `UPDATE`. Но при `INSERT` ничего не записывается в колонку `posts_id`, а при `UPDATE` записываются лишь запятые. В чем может быть проблема?
(В колонку `posts_id` должен записываться `id` новости, которая сейчас создасться. Это кусок скрипта создания поста на сайте).

Заранее спасибо.

```
$row_id = $db->get_row(
  $db->query(
    "SELECT `id`,`alt_name` 
     FROM `". DBPREFIX ."posts` 
     WHERE `alt_name`='{$alt_name}'"));
$row_id = $db->get_row(
  $db->query(
    "INSERT INTO `". DBPREFIX ."posts_data` (`post_id`, `addcomm`)
     VALUES ('{$row_id['id']}', 1);"));

if($tags){
  $tag_a = array();
  $tags = rtrim($tags, ',');
  $tag_a = explode(',', trim($tags));
  foreach($tag_a as $tag){
    $tag_s = $db->get_row(
               $db->query(
                "SELECT * FROM `". DBPREFIX ."tags`
                 WHERE `name`='".trim($tag)."'"));
    if($tag_s['name'] != trim($tag)){
      $db->query(
        "INSERT INTO `". DBPREFIX ."tags` (`name`, `posts_id`)
         VALUES ('". trim($tag) ."', '{$row_id['id']}')");
    } else {
      $tag_i = array();
      $tag_i = explode(',', $tag_s['posts_id']);
      array_push($tag_i, $row_id['id']);
      asort($tag_i);
      $tag_i = implode(',', $tag_i);
      $db->query("UPDATE `". DBPREFIX ."tags`
                  SET posts_id='{$tag_i}'
                  WHERE `name`='". trim($tag) ."'");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю из приведенного вами кода метод `$db->get_row` обертка для возврата данных из `$db->query`.

Но здесь:

```
$row_id = $db->get_row(
  $db->query(
    "SELECT `id`,`alt_name` 
     FROM `". DBPREFIX ."posts` 
     WHERE `alt_name`='{$alt_name}'"));
$row_id = $db->get_row(
  $db->query(
     "INSERT INTO `". DBPREFIX ."posts_data` (`post_id`, `addcomm`) 
      VALUES ('{$row_id['id']}', 1);"));
```

во втором запросе вы делаете `insert`, а при `insert` sql не возвращает `id` новой записи. Получается, что на второй строке, переменной `$row_id` вы присваиваете `null`, и в базу записывается пустая переменная.

По поводу UPDATE

Поскольку у вас `$row['id'] = ''`, `array_push` добавляет новый элемент к массиву `$tag_i` и получается:

```
$tag_i = array (size=1)
    0 => string '' (length=0)
```

И после `implode` получается просто ','

Сперва вам нужно исправить вторую строку приведенного кода.

И отходя от темы - хранить `post_id` в виде строки в одном поле `posts_id` не есть гуд. Вы не сможете работать с этим полем на уровне sql - динамичные выборки, join'ы в этом варианте недоступны.